printing output of subprocess.Popen in a pyQt5 Widget (realtime)
I checked every post regarding this issue and I found either very old posts (2011) or posts with solutions not working or fitting.
My "only" wish is to bring the output of Popen to a QListWidget. My original task is to start a database backup with Popen. There are many output lines I would like to show in a Widget (I've choosen the QListWidget and try to work with .addItem(QListWidgetItem("Text"))).
That's a code snipet for my problem. If it's started, the ListWidget is empty. If the button is pushed the first weird issue I dealt with: why the List is not updated? Normally the first addItem should work?! If the program starts, nothing changes. Only if the program has finished, the lines are added to the ListWidget.
I changed the executable to notepad++. If anybody would really like to try it, these two lines (1) needed to be replaced/customized.
import subprocess
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidgetItem, QListWidget, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QMainWindow


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle('PopenTest')
        self.cw = QWidget()
        self.list = QListWidget(self)
        self.button = QPushButton("Backup!")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.list)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.cw.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.backup)

        self.show()

        # self.mariabackup_path = r"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.4\bin\mariabackup.exe"
        # self.backup_command = [self.mariabackup_path, "--backup"]

        # (1) THESE TWO LINES:
        mariabackup_path = r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
        self.backup_command = [mariabackup_path, "-loadingTime"]

    def backup(self):
        self.list.clear()
        self.list.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Start backup by pushing the button ... "))
        print("Sleeping 1 sec for applying the new lines in self.list ... ")
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            print(f"backup_command for subprocess.run = {self.backup_command}")

            with (subprocess.Popen(
                    self.backup_command,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                    encoding='utf-8',  # errors='replace',
            ) as result):

                while True:
                    realtime_output = result.stdout.readline()
                    if realtime_output == '' and result.poll() is not None:
                        print("Time for break ... ")
                        break
                    if realtime_output:
                        self.info.addItem(QListWidgetItem(realtime_output.strip()))
                        print(f"realtime_output (should be in ListWidget) = "
                              f"{realtime_output}")

        except Exception as excp:
            print(f"Ex: {excp}")
            return

        self.list.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Window closes in 3 sec ..."))
        time.sleep(1)
        self.list.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Window closes in 2 sec ..."))
        time.sleep(1)
        self.list.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Window closes in 1 sec ..."))
        time.sleep(1)
        # self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainW = MyMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


I doubt that you can mix time.sleep() with a GUI framework. Normally the framework needs to be in control all the time, issuing events which update the GUI. (Nor should you have a while loop expecting to update a visual control).

The proper way to do this is to have the GUI hooked to execute a callback which updates the window if any new output has arrived since the previous callback; or perhaps switch to an async architecture.

You're completely blocking everything by using time.sleep() and a while loop. GUI toolkits are normally event driven, meaning that they have an event loop that must be left free to process its events, and whatever function is called in the main thread must therefore return as soon as possible. While there are possible alternatives (forcing event processing or using a separate thread), it doesn't make sense for this purpose. Use QProcess and connect to its readyRead signals.

Thanks, @quamrana for the correct hint:
time.sleep(1) was the troublemaker...
I replaced it with
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()

and
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(5, loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()

within the while True-Loop and now it's working quite nice! That took me almost the whole day... should have asked earlier. Thanks!

Sorry but that's a terrible solution. If you want to force event processing, call QApplication.processEvent(), don't create unnecessary loops (and don't create them repeatedly). Besides, as already pointed out above, if you use QProcess, all that will be done transparently using signals and slots.
